# Maximum of function containing two variables $x$ and $y$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization

> If $x+y+\sqrt{2x^2+2xy+3y^2} = k(\bf{Const.})\;,$ Then $\max(x^2y)\;,$ Where $x,y\geq 0$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Let $x^2y=z\;$ Then we get $$x+\frac{x^2}{z}+\sqrt{2x^2+\frac{2z}{x}+\frac{3z^2}{x^4}} = k$$

Now How can I solve it, Help me

Thanks

Comment: The constraint looks like a semi-circle which you can parametrize by $\sin$ and $\cos$

Comment: @frank000. To me, it does not seem to look like a semi-circle (looking at contour plots). Could you go ahead with your idea of parametrization ?

Comment: $\sqrt{2x^2+2xy+3y^2}=k-x-y \Rightarrow 2x^2+2xy+3y^2=k^2+x^2+y^2-2xk-2yk+2xy\Rightarrow x^2+2y^2+2xk+2yk=k^2\Rightarrow (x+k)^2+2(y+k/2)^2=5k^2/2$, hmm not a circle, an ellipse instead, but ellipse can also be parametrized by sin and cos.

Comment: @frank000. This is a very good point !

Answer (score 2):

**Assuming** $y=a x$ ($a\geq0$), the constraint leads to $$x=\frac{k}{\sqrt{3 a^2+2 a+2}+a+1}$$ and $$x^2y=\frac{a k^3}{\left(\sqrt{3 a^2+2 a+2}+a+1\right)^3}$$ Now, computing $$\frac{d}{da}x^2y=-\frac{(2 a-1) \left(3 a+\sqrt{a (3 a+2)+2}+2\right)}{\sqrt{a (3 a+2)+2}
   \left(a+\sqrt{a (3 a+2)+2}+1\right)^4}k^3$$ which cancels if $a=\frac 12$.

All of this makes a maximum value equal to $$\frac{4 k^3}{\left(3+\sqrt{15}\right)^3}$$

Comment: Thanks Claude Leibovici for Nice solution.

Comment: Can we solve It using any Inequality.Something like $\bf{A.M\geq G.M\, Cauchy-schwartz, }$ or $\bf{Holder\; Inequality.}$

Comment: @juantheron. I really have no idea ! I am very bad with these inequalities (as with many many other things in mathematics). Sorry for that. Cheers. By the way, I enjoy your posts; I learnt a lot from them. Cheers.